# Can I have a div element over a image?

Tags: html, css

I am using a SVG image over that image I need to have a div over the image to set a button area over the image. I have placed a div content in my html file but my image file hides the div content. How to make it?
This my html code:

```
<div class="fancybox" id="nav" href="#inline1"/>
<img src="billing.svg" id="my_image" class="gold1"/>// this is my image over this I need to place the div content
```

This is my CSS file:

```
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#00FF66;
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:9px;          
}
```

Comment: You want that fancy box div over image?

Comment: use z-index to place div over image

Comment: yes.i need that fancy box div over a image

Comment: Do you need it to be a button or could you just wrap it with a `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="outerBoxContent">

    <div class="fancybox" id="nav" href="#inline1"/>
    <img src="billing.svg" id="my_image" class="gold1"/>// this is my image over this I need to place the div content

</div>
```

## css

```
.outerBoxContent{position: relative;}
.outerBoxContent .fancybox{position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;height: 100%;width: 100%:z-index:123}
```

This is how you can place the content over a div.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .fancybox{
    position:relative;
    height://height go image
    width:// of image
    }
    .fancybox img{
    position:absolute;
    height://height go image
    width:// of image
    z-index:-1;
    }

    .myDiv{
    position:absolute;
    width:// width of dive
    z-index:1;
    left://margin from left
    right://margin right
    top:margin from top
    bottom:margin from bottom

}


<div class="fancybox" id="nav" href="#inline1"/>
<img src="billing.svg" id="my_image" class="gold1"/>
<div class="myDiv"></div>

</div>
```